# Get Selected T proprties from one IQueryable<T> into an IQueryable<MyClass>

Tags: c#, class, generics, iqueryable

I have a Generic function that contains an `IQueryable<T>` where each row contains an instance of a class with a set of properties.

I have another class (MyClass) that has some of the same properties as the class T above... i.e. same name and datatypes.

I also have a List of Strings containing the Property Names shared between the two classes.

I want to be able to create a new `IQueryable<myClass>` where the myClass instances properties are populated with the name-sake proprties in the original `IQueryable<T>`

Does that make sense? Please let me know if I can supply any more info or make anything more clear.

EDIT
I will try an add some code to illustrate better. I know there are countless faults here including Adding to an IQueryable - but this is for illustration:

```
IQueryable<T> qry = this.GetSomeDataIntoIQueryable();

// Just getting a list of the Shared Property Names between the two classes
List<string> sharedProprtyNames = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in ListofSharedPropertyNames)
{
    sharedProprtyNames .Add(item.SharedPropertyName);
}

IQueryable<myClass> myClassIQ;
foreach(var classItem in qry)
{
    myClass x = new myClass();
    foreach(var sharedProperty in sharedProprtyNames )
    {
        myClass[sharedProperty] = classItem[sharedProperty];
    }
    myClassIQ.Add(myClass);
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand with code... just saying

Comment: I'll say `IQueryable<SomeTable> query = ...`, `IQueryable<PieceOfTable> query2 = query.BuildSelect<PieceOfTable>(new[] { "Col1", "Col2" })`

Comment: I have added a pseudo-code snippet to the question... hope it helps?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
static IQueryable<TTo> Select<TFrom, TTo>(
     this IQueryable<TFrom> source,
     params string[] members)
{
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFrom));
    var body = Expression.MemberInit(
        Expression.New(typeof(TTo)),
        members.Select(member => Expression.Bind(
            typeof(TTo).GetMember(member).Single(),
            Expression.PropertyOrField(p, member))));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TFrom, TTo>>(body, p);
    return source.Select(lambda);
}
```

?

This creates an `IQueryable<T>`-friendly projection from `TFrom` to `TTo`, respecting all the members from `members`.

In your example, it would be:

```
IQueryable<myClass> myClassIQ = qry.Select<T, myClass>(ListofSharedPropertyNames);
```

(adjust between array / list for the `members` parameter to suit your convenience - because we use `Select`, it'll work with either)

Comment: This is an answer of pure beauty. I tested with two simple objects like `new[] { new Person() { Name = "James", Age = 48 } }.AsQueryable().Select<Person, Thing>(new [] { "Name", "Age" })` and it works perfectly.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, when I try calling it I have an error stating that "IQueryable<T> does not contain a definition for Select..." - this is on the qry.Select in the second code snippet...?

Comment: @CJH try marking the method as `public`, and the type it is in needs to be in scope via the `using` directives at the top of the file (i.e. in a namespace you're already using); the `this` in the parameter makes it an extension method. It works fine locally :) if you can't get it working as an extension method, just use `var foo = TheTypeThatYouPutItIn.Select<T, myClass>(qry, ListofSharedPropertyNames);` - that's exactly the same thing

Comment: Thanks Again Marc - I will take a look at this shortly and updated!

Comment: I am getting the error "Argument types do not match" at the moment... Looking through it now but things seem to match? Any pointers?

Comment: @CJH where exactly? as I said: it was working fine locally - here's my full code: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/b964134dcae9eeaa6243c5e793c92bb4 - if it is failing for you, an example would be great

Comment: Sorry for the Delay... It turns out that the class T being passed in was not what I was expecting... There was some sneaky code that did some witchcraft above which changes the class of T to a pseudo class of the original so wasn't quite matching. because of this problem I am en devouring a different route to my requirement. I will mark this as correct though as Enigmativity above got it working quickly and it does make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/) you can:

```
IQueryable<Table1> query1 = ...
var res = query.Select<SubTable1>("new(" + string.Join(",", new[] { "Col1", "Col2" }) + ")").ToArray();
```

Where `query1` is your query, `Table1` is the `T` of your question, `SubTable1` is `MyClass`, `"Col1", "Col2"` are the columsn that must be selected.

You could do everything without usig the `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` library and simply building an expression tree... But it is a pain :-)

My variant of the code of Hans Passant:

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, IEnumerable<string> columns)
{
    // the x in x => ...
    var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");

    // "Bindings" (the Col1 = x.Col1 inside the x => new { Col1 = x.Col1 })
    var binds = columns.Select(x => Expression.Bind((MemberInfo)typeof(TResult).GetProperty(x) ?? typeof(TResult).GetField(x), Expression.PropertyOrField(par, x)));

    // new TResult
    var new1 = Expression.New(typeof(TResult));

    // new TResult { Bindings }
    var mi = Expression.MemberInit(new1, binds);

    // x => new TResult { Bindings }
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(mi, par);

    // Select(x => new TResult { Bindings })
    return source.Select(lambda);
}
```

(nearly totally equivalent... Only difference is that he uses `GetMember()` while I used `GetProperty()` + `GetField()`)

Comment: Many thanks for that xanatos... I was hoping to come to a solution without needing to introduce any new libraries. I may come back to this though if I have no luck elsewhere.

Comment: "But it is a pain" - it isn't *that* much of a pain :)

Comment: @MarcGravell I know... But it is around 10 lines of pain :-)